# Need your help for a MongoDb Migration to add fields to randomly named nested objects. `connections: { [id: string]: some_object_type }`

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, migration, aggregation-framework

Need some real help on this! And only you can help me!

Currently writing a MongoDb migration and I'm required to add some new fields to a nested object of unknown field name

**Example of document:**

```
{
        "_id" : "1a3a5c0c-4542-4bcc-9965-5c04db8d3edc",
        "name" : "Test_person",
        "connections" : {
                "540e1234-field_random_num" : {
                        "some_field_1" : "Garbage_string_1",
                        "some_field_2" : {
                                "sub_field_1" : 1234,
                                "sub_field_2" : 5678,
                                "sub_field_3" : null,
                        }
                },
                "48925678-field_random_num_2" : {
                        "some_field_1" : "Garbage_string_2",
                        "some_field_2" : {
                                "sub_field_1" : 4321,
                                "sub_field_2" : 8765,
                                "sub_field_3" : null,
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Given this document, where `connections: { [id: string]: some_object_type }`

Note that :

```
some_object_type: {
  some_field_1: string,
  some_field_2: sub_object_type
}
```

and

```
sub_object_type: {
  "sub_field_1" : number
  "sub_field_1" : number
  "sub_field_1" : string
}
```

Have tried using `$[]` which has worked for other collections in the same migration script. Sadly, `$` is not of much help, given that its usage is limited to arrays.

My current train of thought has led me to believe that the right approach lays in the *evaluation query operator* `$where`, in order to isolate the randomly named `id : string` object field

*Long story short... looking for an alternative to the `$[]` operator to use with objects*

**The updated document will look like this:**

```
{
        "_id" : "1a3a5c0c-4542-4bcc-9965-5c04db8d3edc",
        "name" : "Test_person",
        "connections" : {
                "540e1234-field_random_num" : {
                        "some_field_1" : "Garbage_string_1,
                        "some_field_2" : {
                                "sub_field_1" : 1234,
                                "sub_field_2" : 5678,
                                "sub_field_3" : null,
                                "new_sub_field" : null <-- new field
                        }
                },
                "48925678-field_random_num_2" : {
                        "some_field_1" : "Garbage_string_2",
                        "some_field_2" : {
                                "sub_field_1" : 4321,
                                "sub_field_2" : 8765,
                                "sub_field_3" : null,
                                "new_sub_field" : null <-- new field
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get desired result in 2 ways:

**Shell JS:** We can execute JS code with recursive function:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    function _(obj){
        //Iterate
        for(var key in obj){
            //If key is some_field_2, we insert inside new key:value
            if(key == "some_field_2"){
                obj[key]["new_sub_field"] = null;

            // If value is object, we call recursive function
            } else if (typeof(obj[key]) == "object"){
                obj[key] = _(obj[key]);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    print(_(doc))
})
```

**Aggregation:** With [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) we normalize `connection` into `key:value` array.

```
We convert 
{"connection": {"foo":"bar", "buz" : "foobar"}}
into
{"connection": [{"k":"foo", "v":"bar"}, {"k":"buz", "v":"foobar"}]}`
```

We go down till `sub_object_type` field and add new `new_sub_field` field with `$mergeObjects`. To convert normalized array into object, we use `$arrayToObject`

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      connections: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$connections"
            },
            as: "conn",
            in: {
              k: "$$conn.k",
              v: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                  $map: {
                    input: {
                      $objectToArray: "$$conn.v"
                    },
                    as: "some_field",
                    in: {
                      k: "$$some_field.k",
                      v: {
                        $cond: [
                          {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$some_field.k",
                              "some_field_2"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            $mergeObjects: [
                              "$$some_field.v",
                              {
                                "new_sub_field": null
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "$$some_field.v"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GxvFuFS7bXF)

Comment: Thank you so much @Valijon ! This has been of great help, and thank you for sharing the MongoPlayground visualization, which gives me the certainty of your great solution. Keep being a Star in this great SO community

Will seek to increase Rep in order to upvote your top of the line solution!

Best regards from Valencia, Spain!

Comment: @Benito you are welcome, glad to help you. (best regards from Madrid, Spain)